# Connection between principal ideal and Cayley's theorem (?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

A (left) principal ideal $I$ of $(R,+,\times)$ is a subset of $R$ of the form $Ra = \{ra : r \in R\}.$ So, on the multiplication table, the principal ideal is a column (or a row) in the multiplication of the element $a$ with all the other elements of the ring, $R.$

My understanding is the ideal has to form a subgroup under addition.

On the other hand, and within a finite (?) group $G$, I think it's Cayley's theorem that guarantees that each entry in the multiplication table (each column or row) includes a permutation of all the elements in the group.

> I'm asking for help understanding why, then, not all principal ideals contain exactly all the elements in the ring.

Evidently, this monotonous and predictable result wouldn't be of much interest, and I presume the answer is likely to lie in the fact that the set $R$ forms a group under addition, but not under multiplication. Is this the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that a ring $(R, +, \cdot)$ forms an abelian group over addition (that is, $(R, +)$ is an abelian group. Now depending on your definition, $(R, \cdot)$ is considered as either a semigroup or a monoid. (Informally, a semigroup is a group that doesn't have identity and isn't closed under inverses. A monoid is a semigroup with identity). The important point is that not every element of $R \setminus \{0\}$ necessarily has a multiplicative inverse.

The group structure, namely closure under inverses, provides for the cancellation law. In this manner, the natural left action induces a bijection. This is basically the result of Cayley's Theorem.

As not every element of $R \setminus \{0\}$ has a multiplicative inverse, the ring multiplication operation need not induce a bijection. Consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$. We have that $2 \cdot 2 \equiv 2 \cdot 5 \equiv 4 \pmod{6}$. Clearly, $2$ and $5$ are distinct elements in $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$. So while $(2)$ is clearly a principal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$, $(2)$ is a proper ideal of $\mathbb{Z}_{6}$. That is, $(2) \neq \mathbb{Z}_{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have just a simple misunderstanding of some basic definitions.  Consider a simple example to see if that clears things up:

$$\langle 2 \rangle = \{0, \pm 2, \pm 4, \ldots \}$$

in the ring $\langle \mathbb{Z}, +, \cdot, 0,1\rangle $

Clearly the thing above is a principal ideal but it also is not the entire set of all integers.  Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Can you clarify what the $0,1$ stand for in $\langle \mathbb{Z}, +, \cdot, 0,1\rangle?$

Comment: I think @EricWofsey would give a  far more accurate answer, but here I go.....  It's basically the privileged elements of the set $\mathbb{Z}$ ...(in fact, a lot of people prefer to call the set $Z$ and use $\mathbb{Z}$ to speak of $\langle Z,+,\cdot, 0, 1\rangle$). That aside, another way to think of it is that $0$ is the identity for the underlying group structure and $1$ is the multiplicative identity.  But you should probably be satisfied (for now at least) to just think of $\langle Z,+,\cdot, 0, 1\rangle $ as the "formal label" for the group structure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the usual sense.